# Are there any formulas for min(a,b,c)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was wondering if there are formulas such as min$(a,b)=\displaystyle\frac{a+b-|a-b|}{2}$, etc. but for three numbers (a,b,c).

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

$$\min (a,b,c)=\min (\min (a,b ),c) $$

Comment: I remember that min(a,b,c) ≤ (a+b+c) / 3, which helped me solve the problem. Anyway, thanks for your formula!

Comment: Why stop there, Salhamam?  $\min(a, b, c) = \min(a,\min(b, c)),$ as well.  You never appeal to associativity.  $\min(a, b, c) = \min(b, \min(a, c))$, acknowledging the the "minimum operator" is commutative as well as associative.

Comment: @amWhy not salhamam but salahamam.

Comment: Oops! Apologies, @Salahamam .  The correct spelling is what I intended to write, but I see my fingers and/or my keyboard foiled that intention! :)